# How to add wrapper around existing command in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

Is there any way to add to or wrap an existing command?

For example, if someone runs `git pull` it really runs `git pull --rebase`?

Sure, we've written an alias for it, but the issue is that people aren't using the alias.

Is there any way to detect that `git pull` was run and add to it?

An ideal solution?

```
$ git pull
```

echoes out

```
$ This is not the prefered way of pulling down new code. Did you mean to run ~/my_scripts/git_pull_script.sh?
```

And then cancels the original git pull.

There's probably a simpler way to do this kind of thing, but searching around hasn't yielded much on adapting existing commands.

Comment: Is there a directory in everyone's `$PATH` ahead of the directory that contains `git`? You could put a `git` script there that does the extra checks, and then calls the real `git`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concretise the answer by @Barmar you could write a script like this:

```
echo $1
if [ "$1" == "pull" ] ;then
    echo This is not the prefered way of pulling down new code. Did you mean to run ~/my_scripts/git_pull_script.sh?
else
    git $*
fi
```

name it `git` and place it in a directory, that is in the PATH variable of the users before the actual place of the git binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command substitution operator $(command) to run a command and capture its output.

For example, if you want to run a command and capture its output, you can use the following:

```
$(command)
```

This is useful if you want to run a command and capture its output.

Comment: There's nothing in the question about capturing the output of a command. It's about modifying the command itself.